# Unable to add custom folder under app directory in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add custom folder named `foo` inside `app` directory like this `app/foo`. But rails is not able to find module. This is just a example class inside `app/foo/bar.rb`

```
 module Foo
   class Bar
   end
 end
```

so if I try to do `Foo::Bar.new` in console I get `uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)`. But if i remove the namespace from the `bar.rb` file then it works. e.g this will work

```
class Bar
end
```

`Bar.new` works fine is rails console, if i remove namespace from the `bar.rb` file(NOTE: `bar.rb` file is still under `app/foo/bar.rb`. I also tried adding `config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/app/foo"` in `application.rb` file but no luck.

If I put `foo` directly under `api` directory like this `app/api/foo/bar.rb` then it works fine. If I also add `foo` directly under `models` directory then it works fine e.g `app/models/foo/bar.rb`

Whats going on? How can I add `foo` directory under `app` directory ?

`ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` shows the directory `foo` is getting loaded fine.

**UPDATE**

Looks like what I am trying to achieve can't be done without putting the `foo` directory inside some other directory. But it makes sense because if we have `user.rb` file inside `app/models/user.rb` we don't do `class Models::User` we do `class User`. so make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line to application.rb file in order to configure autoloading.

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/foo"
```

for more about this you can read at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

UPDATE

Anything under `app` directory will be autoloaded by default.

for `app/foo/bar.rb`

content should be.

```
class Bar
end
```

if you need to make it something like this.

```
module Foo
   class Bar
   end
end
```

then your directory structure should be `app/custom_folder_name/foo/bar.rb`

I will recommend to use `custom_folder_name` as `extras`

Comment: I have already tired `autoload_paths` it doesn't work. Also my understanding is that Rails will autoload anything under `app` directory so that should not be needed.